# Cannot get 2 records based on max date field in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a SQL script in Visual Studio and I have 2 tables, one called `ATB` which has unique rows for `Account ID`s and a second table that has `AccountID` too and another column  called `SettlementTypeID`, this second column has duplicate values as it keeps a record of changes done on the `AccountID` which mean it can have 10 rows with the same `AccountID` but with a different `Lastmodified` date column.

I'm doing a join between them to get the `SettlementTypeID` for each `AccountID` on table `ATB` using the `MAX(LastModifiedDate)` to avoid getting the duplicate values but for some `AccountIDs` is not working at all

Below is my current Code:

```
SELECT 
    t.AccountID,
    r.SettlementTypeID,
    r.LastModifiedDate
FROM
    (SELECT 
         accs.AccountID,
         accs.SettlementTypeID,
         MAX(accs.LastModifiedDate) AS LastModifiedDate
     FROM 
         AccountSettlement accs
     INNER JOIN 
         #ATB atb WITH (nolock) ON atb.AccountID = accs.AccountID
     WHERE
         atb.ReferenceType = 'Settlement' 
         AND atb.SettlementType IS NULL
     GROUP BY 
         accs.AccountID, accs.SettlementTypeID) r
INNER JOIN 
    AccountSettlement t ON t.AccountID = r.AccountID 
                        AND t.SettlementTypeID = r.SettlementTypeID 
                        AND t.LastModifiedDate = r.LastModifiedDate
```

I do not know what am I doing wrong but when I remove the `SettlementTypeID` column and just leave the `accountID` and `LastmodifiedDate` columns it works as expected.

Below there is an small portion of what I'm getting:

[image: Data being pulled]

And this is the data that the script should be providing based on the max date found:

[image]

Comment: Can you add example data and expected results, please?  Also, tag your dbms.

Comment: When I look a the small portion only, if you group by AccountID and SettlementID, it will still have duplicate AccountID, because SettlementID differs. Example 118979 with SettlementID 1 and 7. That is the reason it works when you remove the SettlementID...